# How to calculate variance of least squares estimator using QR decomposition in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, least-squares, qr-decomposition

I'm trying to learn QR decomposition, but can't figure out how to get the variance of beta_hat without resorting to traditional matrix calculations.  I'm practising with the `iris` data set, and here's what I have so far:

```
y<-(iris$Sepal.Length)
x<-(iris$Sepal.Width)
X<-cbind(1,x)
n<-nrow(X)
p<-ncol(X)
qr.X<-qr(X)
b<-(t(qr.Q(qr.X)) %*% y)[1:p]
R<-qr.R(qr.X)
beta<-as.vector(backsolve(R,b))
res<-as.vector(y-X %*% beta)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### setup (copying in your code)

```
y <- iris$Sepal.Length
x <- iris$Sepal.Width
X <- cbind(1,x)
n <- nrow(X)
p <- ncol(X)
qr.X <- qr(X)
b <- (t(qr.Q(qr.X)) %*% y)[1:p]  ## can be optimized; see Remark 1 below
R <- qr.R(qr.X)  ## can be optimized; see Remark 2 below
beta <- as.vector(backsolve(R, b))
res <- as.vector(y - X %*% beta)
```

#### math

[image]

#### computation

Residual degree of freedom is `n - p`, so estimated variance is

```
se2 <- sum(res ^ 2) / (n - p)
```

Thus, the variance covariance matrix of estimated coefficients is

```
V <- chol2inv(R) * se2

#           [,1]         [,2]
#[1,]  0.22934170 -0.07352916
#[2,] -0.07352916  0.02405009
```

#### validation

Let's check the correctness by comparing with `lm`:

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)

vcov(fit)

#            (Intercept) Sepal.Width
#(Intercept)  0.22934170 -0.07352916
#Sepal.Width -0.07352916  0.02405009
```

Identical result!

---

#### Remark 1 (skip forming 'Q' factor)

Instead of `b <- (t(qr.Q(qr.X)) %*% y)[1:p]`, you can use function `qr.qty` (to avoid forming 'Q' matrix):

```
b <- qr.qty(qr.X, y)[1:p]
```

#### Remark 2 (skip forming 'R' factor)

You don't have to extract `R <- qr.R(qr.X)` for `backsolve`; using `qr.X$qr` is sufficient:

```
beta <- as.vector(backsolve(qr.X$qr, b))
```

---

#### Appendix: A function for estimation

The above is the simplest demonstration. In practice column pivoting and rank-deficiency need be dealt with. The following is an implementation. `X` is a model matrix and `y` is the response. Results should be compared with `lm(y ~ X + 0)`.

```
qr_estimation <- function (X, y) {
  ## QR factorization
  QR <- qr(X)
  r <- QR$rank
  piv <- QR$pivot[1:r]
  ## estimate identifiable coefficients
  b <- qr.qty(QR, y)[1:r]
  beta <- backsolve(QR$qr, b, r)
  ## fitted values
  yhat <- base::c(X[, piv] %*% beta)
  ## residuals
  resi <- y - yhat
  ## error variance
  se2 <- base::c(crossprod(resi)) / (nrow(X) - r)
  ## variance-covariance for coefficients
  V <- chol2inv(QR$qr, r) * se2
  ## post-processing on pivoting and rank-deficiency
  p <- ncol(X)
  beta_full <- rep.int(NA_real_, p)
  beta_full[piv] <- beta
  V_full <- matrix(NA_real_, p, p)
  V_full[piv, piv] <- V
  ## return
  list(coefficients = beta_full, vcov = V_full,
       fitted.values = yhat, residuals = resi, sig = sqrt(se2))
  }
```